# Show that the following function is always positive

Tags: functions, inequality

For any $r>0$ and positive integer $n$ define the following function

$$f_r(n) = \frac{1}{(nr)^{1/5}} - 4 \log \Big(\frac{3}{n^2}\Big)$$

I plotted the above function for multiple values of $r$ and it seems to be always greater than zero for any $n \geq 2$. How can I prove this?

At first, I thought maybe the derivative with respect to $n$ is always positive (and thus the function is positive for $n \geq c$, where $f_r(c) = 0$) but this turned out not to be the case:

$$\frac{\partial f_r(n)}{\partial n} = -\frac{1}{5} r^{-1/5}n^{-6/5} + 8n^{-1},$$

which can be negative when $r$ is very small.

Comment: If $n\ge \sqrt 3$ then $4\log(\frac 3{n^2})$ is negative

Comment: The derivative will tell you when a function is increasing or decreasing; it won't tell you when the values are negative or positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log(3/n^2) < 0$ for $n \ge 2$, so $f_r(n)$ is the sum of two positive numbers.